# Managing git repos

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and am unsure of a few things, would really appreciate if someone could answer the below questions.

So I own 2 private git repos. Repo1 has numerous developers contributing. Repo2 is only for me. I want to be able to basically take a copy Repo1, make changes and push only to Repo2. In the end Repo2 should be the final repo.

1. From what I have read I think I should fork Repo1?
2. Assuming forking is the way to go - will the contributors of Repo1 get notified that I have forked it?
3. Can I merge any changes made to Repo1 after I have forked into Repo2 easily?
4. Can the contributors of Repo1 see any of my other repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, that's the common way to do it.
2. They only get notified if they are on github or other collaboration platforms.You could easily just clone the repo, do your stuff and nobody will have knowledge of that.
3. This depends on your changes. Merging back typically is done in a pull request.
4. This depends if you are on collaboration platform like github. If so, they can see who forked and can see your contributions so far.

You can do the following: Fork their repo via github or just cloning(then you need to add a new remote to a repo you own and push it to the new location).

Comment: I would rather they did not get notified that it is forked so I will clone. I own both repos so do I add the remote to Repo2(the one I will be pushing too)?

Comment: @LornaKelly: Exactly, clone repo 1 and add a remote to repo 2 and then you push only to this new remote.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone repo1 and create a local branch in which you'll introduce your changes. As long as you don't push this branch to the remote repo1, your changes will not be visible remotely to others. They will be local to your cloned repo.

Now, if you'd like to maintain a private remote repo (e.g. repo2), you can add a remote repo to your local repo and push your branch to it.

As for merging from repo1 to your version of the code base, you can pull from repo1, merge to your local branch and push it to repo2.

Others cannot see repo2 since you added it locally as another remote repo.